# Intellij not connecting to Postgres

Tags: postgresql, intellij-idea

I can connect to postgres just fine using pgadmin4. I cannot connect using Intellij.  I'm getting from Intellij: `[28P01] FATAL: password authentication failed for user "admin"`

Intellij is attempting to connect to the database but finishes with: `2023-05-14 07:03:46,333 [1806050]   INFO - #c.i.e.r.RemoteProcessSupport - Process finished with exit code -1`.

Intellij's database plugins are updated. Note:  I can connect to mysql just fine through Intellij.

Pertinent Postgres server configuration:

```
ALLOW_SAVE_PASSWORD = True
ALLOW_SAVE_TUNNEL_PASSWORD = False
APP_COPYRIGHT = "Copyright (C) 2013 - 2023, The pgAdmin Development Team"
APP_ICON = "pg-icon"
APP_NAME = "pgAdmin 4"
APP_RELEASE = 7
APP_REVISION = 1
APP_SUFFIX = ""
APP_VERSION = "7.1"
APP_VERSION_INT = 70100
AUTHENTICATION_SOURCES = ['internal']
AUTO_DISCOVER_SERVERS = True
DEFAULT_SERVER = "127.0.0.1"
DEFAULT_SERVER_PORT = 5050
DESKTOP_USER = "pgadmin4@pgadmin.org"
EFFECTIVE_SERVER_PORT = 55627
```

I did notice the host properties for Intellij is set to port 5432, while the DEFAULT_SERVER_PORT = 5050.  Changing the ports did not help. I also went into the `pg_hba` conf files and changed the method from scram-sha-256 to md5 to no effect.

Comment: This may require some troubleshooting. Therefore, please create a ticket

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=DBE

and attach the idea log from Help - Show Log in Files

Answer (score 0):

I was running a standalone version of pgadmin4 locally. When I ran pgadmin and postgres in docker containers I was able to connect with no problems.